# What are the smallest values that can no longer be represented exactly in C decimal point datatypes?

Tags: c, floating-point, precision

For example: What is the smallest `uint32_t` value that can no longer be represented exactly as a `double`? etc.

And how to calculate these values?

Comment: Integers are a bad example, as integer types can represent *all* values in the range of the type. Floating-point types are a different issue. For that see e.g. [this limits of floating-point types reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits#Limits_of_floating-point_types)

Comment: I think the C23 standard covers decimal floating-point types, but `uint32_t` isn't a 'decimal point' type. It represents *exact* integer values within the specified range.

Comment: Re the edit: every value of `uint32_t` can be exactly represented by `double`, because its significand has more than 32 bits.

Comment: `double` is not a decimal point datatype. All `uint32_t` values are exactly representable as `double` (in an IEEE-754 compliant implementation).

Comment: @n.m. C does allow `double` as _decimal_, even though it is quite rare these days.  Conformance to  IEEE-754 is not needed either to allow us to know C requires a `double` to encode all `uint32_t` exactly given `DBL_DIG >= 10`.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the smallest `uint32_t` value that can no longer be represented exactly as a `double`?

All `uint32_t` can be exactly represented as a `double` as C specifies `DBL_DIG >= 10` results in C encoding *exactly* at least all consecutive integers values [-10<sup>10</sup> to +10<sup>10</sup>].  That encompasses all `uint32_t`.

---

> how to calculate these values?

Refer to the C spec.

The **minimal** continuous range of integers value exactly encodable as a floating point type is specified by C primarily by:

```
FLT_DIG 6
DBL_DIG 10
LDBL_DIG 10
```

In the case of `float`, all 6 decimal digit integers are representable [-999,999.0 to +999,999.0] including +/- 1,000,000. Starting from zero and going down, the first negative integer value that may not be representable as a `float` is -1,000,001.  This is the minimum range when `FLT_RADIX == 10`, which hardly exists anymore.

When `FLT_RADIX == 2` (very common), the number of binary digits `p` in the significand is:

```
(p-1)*log10(2) >= xxx_DIG
```

solving this for `float`, `p` is at least 20.  With `p == 20`, `float` can exactly encode integers [-2<sup>20</sup> to +2<sup>20</sup>] or [-1,048,576 to +1,048,576].

So much for spec minimums.

---

**Common limit**

Typical [`float`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) with its sign bit and 24 binary digits has a wider range than the C spec minimum.  It exactly encodes integers [-2<sup>24</sup> to +2<sup>24</sup>].  The first negative integer value that is not representable: -2<sup>24</sup> - 1 or -16,777,217.

Answer (score 2):

What `float` and `double` are varies based on compiler, and it chooses based on the architecture.  On an x86 or x86-64, a `float` is likely an IEEE single-precision floating point number, and `double` is likely an IEEE double-precision floating point number.

| Type | Range of continuously representable integers (Inclusive bounds) | Size of this range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| uint16_t | 0 .. 2^16-1 | 2^16 |
| uint32_t | 0 .. 2^32-1 | 2^32 |
| uint64_t | 0 .. 2^64-1 | 2^64 |
| IEEE single-precision | -2^24 .. 2^24 | 2^25+1 |
| IEEE double-precision | -2^53 .. 2^53 | 2^54+1 |

An IEEE single-precision float has 24 bits of precision.<sup>[1]</sup> It can exactly represent far larger numbers than those mentioned above, but it can't represent 2^24+1 or -2^24-1 exactly.

An IEEE double-precision float has 53 bits of precision.<sup>[1]</sup> It can exactly represent far larger numbers than those mentioned above, but it can't represent 2^53+1 or -2^53-1 exactly.

---

1. Subnormals (extremely small numbers) have less precision.

Answer (score 1):

​1. You have a principal discrepancy in your question: you have said for "decimal point" datatypes but then mentioned "double".

`double`, in utmost majority of available implementations, is not decimal point type, it is binary point type (IEEE754 64-bit decimal). You might look more detailed in Internet and literature how they differ.

For the following Iʼll assume binary `double` and not (really rarely present and used) truly decimal types.

​2. Thatʼs, well, simple but a tiny bit tricky:))

I will assume that a platform you refer natively implements IEEE754 and, `float` is 32-bit binary IEEE number and `double` is 64-bit binary IEEE number.
In this case, `float` has 24-bit mantissa with leading 1 (we donʼt count denormals here) and we need the smallest value which, *not including leading trailing zeros*, does not fit into 24 bits. (No need to check exponent range for the question.)

For the following, "0b" is binary prefix and "**" is power operator.

16777215 = 2**24-1 is 0b111111111111111111111111 (24 consecutive ones). It fits.

16777216 = 2**24 is 0b1000000000000000000000000 (one and 24 consecutive zeros). It fits.

16777217 = 2**24+1 is 0b1000000000000000000000001 (one, 23 consecutive zeros, and one). It does not fit.

"Float" can represent: ..., 16777214, 16777215, 16777216, 16777218, 16777220, 16777222... so starting with 16777216 = 2**24, step between representable values is 2.

So, the minimum unsigned integer, not representable in "float", is 16777217.

No need to copy all these long string bits for other case - with `double` with its 53-bit mantissa, it would be just cumbersome. I hope the principle is declared well. For your concrete example, it means that any `uint32_t` value can be exactly represented in `double` but not in `float`.

​3. Also, for `uint32_t` and `double` you could merely have checked declared accuracy. `uint32_t` is up to 10 decimal digits (9 guaranteed). `double` is up to 17 decimal digits required to exactly represent any value, and 15 guaranteed to represent in it. There is obvious difference between ranges so there is no need for more precise boundary checks.